# embeding v8 into a c++ aplication in visual studio 2012

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, embedded-v8

I've just finished building V8 on windows 8 with visual studio 2012 and now I'd like to statically link it to an application

except I have no idea where to go from here I got some code from google that I'd like to try and compile though

```
#include <v8.h>

using namespace v8;

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  // Get the default Isolate created at startup.
  Isolate* isolate = Isolate::GetCurrent();

  // Create a stack-allocated handle scope.
  HandleScope handle_scope(isolate);

  // Create a new context.
  Handle<Context> context = Context::New(isolate);

  // Here's how you could create a Persistent handle to the context, if needed.
  Persistent<Context> persistent_context(isolate, context);

  // Enter the created context for compiling and
  // running the hello world script. 
  Context::Scope context_scope(context);

  // Create a string containing the JavaScript source code.
  Handle<String> source = String::New("'Hello' + ', World!'");

  // Compile the source code.
  Handle<Script> script = Script::Compile(source);

  // Run the script to get the result.
  Handle<Value> result = script->Run();

  // The persistent handle needs to be eventually disposed.
  persistent_context.Dispose();

  // Convert the result to an ASCII string and print it.
  String::AsciiValue ascii(result);
  printf("%s\n", *ascii);
  return 0;
}
```

I know it will just bring a compile error if I try and include the v8 header with doing something else and thats what I want to know,

I apologize for the lack of information given, to be quite honest I'm not entirely sure what's needed to help solve my problem so any comments regarding that are also appreciated

Comment: what is compile error you are getting?

Comment: you should find v8base.lib and link to it. But I doubt you can do statically, you need v8.dll